# How change Ubuntu 16.04 window control buttons only?

Tags: 16.04, unity, files, window-buttons, style

How change Ubuntu 16.04 window control button only without additional plugin/package?

Currently my machine simply running Ubuntu 16.04 X11 Unity and with extra tool called as Plank.

How to tweak the appearance of control button (maximize, minimize and close only) of every window? Which file should I edit? is it use code to apply styling or simply by image such png/gif/jpg?

To make it clear below is what I try to do:

Now (I try to change this 3 button only):

[image: Click here to view image]

To:

[image: Click here to view image]